# git rebase with conflict loses commit comments

Tags: git, rebase

1. I had project changes locally however I knew the remote repository (origin) also had some changes that I didn't have locally yet.
2. I commit my local changes as normal (on master) with comments (-m). Let's call this commit 'THE FIRST COMMIT'.
3. `git fetch origin`
4. Just to be sure I do: `git checkout master`
5. `git rebase origin/master`
6. There are conflicts in 2 files. The conflicts are marked as normal with the conflict markers (<<<<< HEAD etc.). Top-half shows what is in origin/master and bottom-half shows what is in my master version.
   After the closing marker (i.e. >>>>>>) it shows part of a line that is in the origin/master version (apparently this is a patch or something) I don't understand this.
7. I make both files as I want them and remove all conflict marker tags etc.
8. `git add .`
9. `git commit` with a comment (-m) in which I say I resolved some merge conflicts. Let's call this commit 'CONFLICT RESOLVE COMMIT'.
10. `git rebase --continue` this complains that there are no changes. I can't continue, there are no more conflicts. `git status` says 'all conflicts fixed' run 'git rebase --continue'. The only option seems 'git rebase --skip' to skip 'the patch' whatever that is.
11. `git rebase --skip` after status says your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit, working tree clean etc. Ok that's as expected.
12. `git log` Shows all the commits in the order I want them except 'THE FIRST COMMIT' is nowhere to be seen it only shows the 'CONFLICT RESOLVE COMMIT' at the top. With the commits that came from origin/master directly underneath it. The changes are still there in all the files (the ones that had conflicts as well as other ones that were changed) so I didn't loose the actual changes.

Why doesn't it show 'THE FIRST COMMIT' with the comments I gave there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went wrong on step 9. You should not be committing new commits in the middle of a rebase operation where you are resolving conflicts. At step 9, instead of running `git commit -m "..."`, you should have run `git rebase --continue`. Incidentally, this is why `git rebase --continue` is complaining in step 10.

In general, you can run `git status` and git will tell you the options you're most likely to want to do. For example, if you ran `git status` after step 8, it would have said, `(all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")`.

---

You have probably destroyed the original commit you're looking for (since it does not appear in your log). It was replaced by "CONFLICT RESOLVE COMMIT" which you ran in step 9. You have some options:

- Don't worry about it, you're files are all still there, and you've lost a tiny bit of history.
- OR, Interactively rebase (google `git rebase -i`) to change the commit message to whatever you want.
- OR, use `git reflog` (google it) to get back your original commit, and try the rebase again.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is the reason. I wasn't quite sure about doing the commit of the changes it seemed weird but I was following: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/
Which then links to a 'standard procedure for resolving merge conflicts' which tells you to commit the changes that resolve the merge. But, if I understand correctly now: This is only when the conflict is because of a merge command which just aborts when the merge fails. Not when you're in a rebase that is on 'hold' because there is a conflict and you still can continue.

Comment: It was once the case that `git rebase --continue` was fussy about whether you did an earlier `git commit`, but that should, in any modern Git, just work automatically now. It's possible that @DelBerrydelberry has an old Git, I suppose...

Comment: Yeah, perhaps an older version of git... I've never seen any case where you'd need to run a `git commit` before `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding here: I don't need to run `git commit` before `git rebase --continue` after resolving conflicts. In fact I now understand that's a bad idea because it will replace the commit comments that rebase will use with those you gave to the 'resolve conflicts commit' and also will give a confusing message that it can't continue because there are no changes (so you can only do `git rebase --skip`).